# 7zip cmd extracting using ProcessBuilder in java

Tags: java, cmd, extract, processbuilder, 7zip

I have a problem extracting an archive to the desired category using Java 10 ProcessBuilder and 7z.exe (18.05) with command line. The exact same command works as intended when I use Windows CMD, but no longer functions when issued by my JavaFX application using ProcessBuilder:

```
    public static void decompress7ZipEmbedded(File source, File destination) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
            getSevenZipExecutablePath(),
            EXTRACT_WITH_FULL_PATHS_COMMAND,
            quotifyPath(source.getAbsolutePath()),
            OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_SWITCH + quotifyPath(destination.getAbsolutePath())
    );
    processWithSevenZipEmbedded(pb);
}

   private static void processWithSevenZipEmbedded(ProcessBuilder pb) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    LOG.info("7-zip command issued: " + String.join(" ", pb.command()));
    Process p = pb.start();
    new Thread(new InputConsumer(p.getInputStream())).start();
    System.out.println("Exited with: " + p.waitFor());
}

   public static class InputConsumer implements Runnable {
        private InputStream is;

        InputConsumer(InputStream is) {
            this.is = is;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                int value = -1;
                while ((value = is.read()) != -1) {
                    System.out.print((char) value);
                }
            } catch (IOException exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }
            LOG.debug("Output stream completed");
        }
    }

public static String getSevenZipExecutablePath() {
    return FileUtil.quotifyPath(getDirectory() + "7z" + "/" + "7z");
}

public static String quotifyPath(String path) {
    return '"' + path + '"';
}

public class Commands {

    public static final String EXTRACT_COMMAND = "e";
    public static final String EXTRACT_WITH_FULL_PATHS_COMMAND = "x";
    public static final String PACK_COMMAND = "a";
    public static final String DELETE_COMMAND = "d";
    public static final String BENCHMARK_COMMAND = "b";
    public static final String LIST_COMMAND = "l";

}

public class Switches {

    public static final String OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_SWITCH = "-o";
    public static final String RECURSIVE_SWITCH = "-r";
    public static final String ASSUME_YES = "y";
}
```

The command looks like this:

```
"C:/Users/blood/java_projects/AppRack/target/classes/7z/7z" x "D:\Pulpit\AppRack Sandbox\test\something\Something 2\Something2.7z" -o"D:\Pulpit\AppRack Sandbox\Something2"
```

And the output from ProcessBuilder:

```
7-Zip 18.05 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2018 Igor Pavlov : 2018-04-30

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 59177077 bytes (57 MiB)

Extracting archive: D:\Pulpit\AppRack Sandbox\test\Something\Something 2\Something2.7z
--
Path = D:\Pulpit\AppRack Sandbox\test\Something\Something 2\Something2.7z
Type = 7z
Physical Size = 5917Exited with: 0
7077
Headers Size = 373
Method = LZMA2:26 LZMA:20 BCJ2
Solid = +
Blocks = 2


No files to process
Everything is Ok

Files: 0
Size:       0
Compressed: 59177077
```

It doesn't do ANYTHING. Doesn't create a desired folder, nothing. Using CMD it works like a charm (here log from Windows 10 CMD using **the same command**):

```
7-Zip 18.05 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2018 Igor Pavlov : 2018-04-30

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 59177077 bytes (57 MiB)

Extracting archive: D:\Pulpit\AppRack Sandbox\test\Something\Something 2\Something2.7z
--
Path = D:\Pulpit\AppRack Sandbox\test\Something\Something 2\Something2.7z
Type = 7z
Physical Size = 59177077
Headers Size = 373
Method = LZMA2:26 LZMA:20 BCJ2
Solid = +
Blocks = 2

Everything is Ok

Folders: 1
Files: 5
Size:       64838062
Compressed: 59177077
```

Do you have any idea what causes a difference here and why it says "No files to process, everything is ok" without doing anything? I've tried already to create a folder first using File class but it doesn't seem to be an issue because the results are the same whether the destination folder exists prior to extracting or not.

I've already tried everything that has come to my mind and I run out of ideas at the moment. Please share with me any suggestions that you may have regarding this issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Don’t quote your arguments.  Quotes are for the command shell’s benefit.  ProcessBuilder is not a command shell;  it executes a command directly, so any quotes are seen as part of the argument itself (that is, the file name).  Also, `pb.inheritIO();` is a better way to see the output of the child process than manually consuming process streams.

Comment: Double click on file `7zip.chm` or start 7-Zip and open the __Help__ and read the help page __Command Line Version - Syntax__ with first line `7z <command> [<switch>...] <base_archive_name> [<arguments>...]`. There is clearly explained that first the command `x` must be specified, next should be the switches like `-o` with best last switch being `--`, then the archive file name and last further arguments like names of files/folders to extract. Switches can be also specified after archive file name, but that is not recommended although examples on help page for `-o` are also with `-o` at end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for your help.

> Don’t quote your arguments. Quotes are for the command shell’s benefit. ProcessBuilder is not a command shell; it executes a command directly, so any quotes are seen as part of the argument itself (that is, the file name). Also, pb.inheritIO(); is a better way to see the output of the child process than manually consuming process streams.

Thank you @VGR it seemed to be the issue - after I remove the method to quote paths in the mentioned command it works like a charm and extracting archive without any problem! So the conclusion is I shouldn't have used quotes in paths while using Java ProcessBuilder.

I've also used pb.inheritIO() and you are right it is much better and easier to manage it this way.

```
public static void decompress7ZipEmbedded(File source, File destination) throws IOException {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder().inheritIO().command(
            getSevenZipExecutablePath(),
            EXTRACT_WITH_FULL_PATHS_COMMAND,
            source.getAbsolutePath(),
            OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_SWITCH + destination.getAbsolutePath(),
            OVERWRITE_WITHOUT_PROMPT
    );
    processWithSevenZipEmbedded(pb);
}

private static void processWithSevenZipEmbedded(ProcessBuilder pb) throws IOException {
    LOG.info("7-zip command issued: " + String.join(" ", pb.command()));
    pb.start();
}

public class Commands {
    public static final String EXTRACT_WITH_FULL_PATHS_COMMAND = "x"; 
}

public class Switches {
    public static final String OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_SWITCH = "-o";
    public static final String OVERWRITE_WITHOUT_PROMPT = "-aoa";
}
```

> Double click on file 7zip.chm or start 7-Zip and open the Help and read the help page Command Line Version - Syntax with first line 7z  [...]  [...]. There is clearly explained that first the command x must be specified, next should be the switches like -o with best last switch being --, then the archive file name and last further arguments like names of files/folders to extract. Switches can be also specified after archive file name, but that is not recommended although examples on help page for -o are also with -o at end.

Thank you @Mofi for the tip. I used -aoa switch instead of -y and it finally started to work as I wanted - to overwrite files without any prompt. I left the rest of the command the way it was as it works as intended, so it finally looks like this:

```
C:/Users/blood/java_projects/AppRack/target/classes/7z/7z" x D:\Pulpit\AppRack Sandbox\test\Test\Test 2\Test.7z -oD:\Desktop\AppRack Sandbox\Test 2 -aoa
```

Thanks a lot for help once again!